# Excel - Get last match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to match the rows in this table into pairs using the following logic:

1. Using Relevant rows only (Column Q = TRUE).
2. Every pair has the same "ParkingName" (Column D).
3. The First row on each pair has a SerialNumber greater than zero (Column B), the second row has 0 as its SerialNumber.
4. The TimeStamp of the second row of each pair is "bigger" than the TimeStamp of the first row (occurs later).

I thought about assigning the first row ID (column A) into the second-row Match column (Column R) of each pair, but any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Table]

Comment: Did you try sorting the data, according to your criteria, and read the pairs from there?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you please demonstrate the expected outcome a bit further?

Comment: Thanks guys, I was actually able to do it using a complex Lookup function.

Comment: Each pair represents login and logout time, the main goal was to calculate the duration of every login, using these pairs.

Comment: Can you provide your final formula?